# Meteor Publish/Subscribe with limit does not return new records

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

I have a very large collection (100k or more) that I don't want to return the whole collection, nor render. I have used the [Template-Level Subscriptions](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/) pattern. However, I am sorting by the newest documents first. When newer documents are added, they don't show up and push the other documents down, off the page.

I'd like to:

- Show the newest 100 documents
- Allow them to view more as needed
- But always show the latest records

Is there a way to do this?